# In app purchase Storekit SwiftUI button grayed out after purchase is complete in iOS 17

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, storekit

I'm testing `In App Purchase` for my iOS app using iOS 17 with SwiftUI.

After successfully making a purchase the buy button is grayed out. This way I cannot test the purchase again. I even deleted the app and reinstalled it, but the button is still grayed out, like shown in the picture below.

[image]

This is the code I'm using. How do I enable the purchase button again?

```
import SwiftUI
import StoreKit

struct InAppPurchaseDetailView: View {
    var item:InAppItems
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            
            VStack {
                ProductView(id: item.identifier) {
                    Image(iconName)
                        .resizable()
                             .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                             .frame(maxWidth: 120, maxHeight: 120)
                             .cornerRadius(10)
                }
                .productViewStyle(.large)
                .padding()
                .onInAppPurchaseStart { product in
                    print("User has started buying \(product.id)")
                }
                .onInAppPurchaseCompletion { product, result in
                    if case .success(.success(let transaction)) = result {
                        print("Purchased successfully: \(transaction.signedDate)")
                    } else {
                        print("Something else happened")
                    }
                }
            }
        }             
        .onAppear() {
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: what do you expect? button to be enabled all the times? Is this a store kit button or your custom button? Until you delete the sandbox transaction tied to your email, you cannot make another purchase.

Comment: This is a Storekit button, not custom. How do I delete the sandbox transaction?

Comment: if you have a test store kit config file added in Xcode, when you run the app, there will be a store kit window you can open from debug options, which will have all transactions you made with the test store kit config